# What is the reason I can't connect a Seagate Personal Cloud device to a Switch

Tags: router, nas, switch

I have a Seagate Personal Cloud, a consumer NAS device with minimal instructions or documentation which expects to be connected via an ethernet cable to a wireless router so that it can be found on a local network.

I don't have access to a router but I do have a switch. However, I can't find the device on the other computers attached to the switch and, asking Seagate's support people online, I'm told that it isn't possible to do what I want.

My question (as a networking non-professional) is: why not? What is the difference, as far as the NAS is concerned, between being attached to a router and being attached to a switch?

The switch is a 3com OfficeConnect dual speed switch, and its status lights report traffic of some sort to and from the port it's connected to. In other respects it seems to be working: e.g. I can print to a network printer attached to it.

Comment: Is there a DHCP server on the network? "can't find the machine" - is network discovery on?

Comment: How are you expecting the NAS device to know what IP address to use?